# Why "no method named `execute` found" when using diesel::insert_into?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel, rust-rocket

I have a problem when I use `diesel::insert_into` to insert data into the database:

```
table! {
    post (id) {
        id -> Integer,
        username -> Varchar,
        postdata -> Varchar,
    }
}
```

```
pub fn create_new_post(post: Post, conn: DbConn) {
    diesel::insert_into(post::table)
            .values(&post)
            .execute(&*conn);
}
```

```
6 |             .execute(&*conn);
  |              ^^^^^^^ method not found in `InsertStatement<table, ValuesClause<(ColumnInsertValue<columns::id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Integer, &i32>>, ColumnInsertValue<columns::username, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Text, &std::string::String>>, ColumnInsertValue<columns::postdata, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Text, &std::string::String>>), table>>`
  |
  = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
  = note: the following trait is implemented but not in scope; perhaps add a `use` for it:
          `use crate::diesel::RunQueryDsl;
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 7):

As the compiler error message is telling you, you miss a `use crate::diesel::RunQueryDsl;` in your current module. That means the corresponding trait is not in scope.